# Access: Find records where duplicate values in one field and contradicting values in another are found

Tags: ms-access

So I have a lot of data which is stock adjustments, some are gains and some are losses.

I need to find all the records which net to £0.

They are from multiple locations.

I have data like this:

```
Store Code     Product Code.    Adjust Cost
AA1                  12345.             £20
AA1                  12345.            -£20
AA1.                 12345.             £40
AAB                  45567.             £14
AAB                  43256.            -£14
```

I also have a field which concats Store Code and Product Code to create a unique value to each store that has adjusted that code.

From the data above I will be looking to select only these records

```
AA1                  12345.                £20
AA1                  12345.               -£20
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: have you tried `VALUE1 + VALUE2 = 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```sql
SELECT * FROM MyTable t
WHERE (SELECT Sum(i.[Adjust Cost]) FROM MyTable i WHERE i.[Store Code] = t.[Store Code]) = 0
```

Comment: That works as it needs too! But it is very slow  how would I remove some records by filtering on a couple of other fields that are in the table? Like product category or removing anything that is already £0? Thanks!

Comment: If it's slow, start by making sure `[Store Code]` is indexed, that can save a lot of time. If you want to add filters, that really depends on your intention. Filtering in the subquery (between the parentheses) causes some records to be excluded from the net value calculation, filtering in the outer query (appending `WHERE condition` at the bottom) filters returned records, but not the net value calculation

Comment: And as far as filtering goes, if the cost is already zero then I don't need to calculate those records and certain categories I don't need to calculate.

Comment: Filtering out records or categories with `0` as cost is usually about as fast or slower than just summing up `0`s if the fields are properly indexed. Indexes are the key to optimizing this query.